# I want to write if statement if my case 1 executes in java

Tags: java

I have few switch cases if case 1 is going to be executed then i need to send mail with an attachment otherwise for other switch cases only an email should be sent. below is my switch cases.How can i write an if statement if my case1 executes.

```
switch (case) 
{
    case assigning:

        break;
```

Comment: Flag variables are invented for this kind of purposes!

Comment: Err, put the code you need for each case inside the corresponding `case` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember in a separate variable which case was selected, then use that value later:

```
boolean needAttachment = false;
switch (os) 
{
    case ASSIGN_TO_ADMIN:
        // other stuff
        needAttachment = true;
        break;
    // other cases, where attachment is not sent
}
if (needAttachment)
{
    sendEmailWithAttachment(toList, ccList);
} else {
    sendEmailWithoutAttachment(toList, ccList);
}
```